# Unable to use initializer list to assign values if structure contains a constructor

Tags: c++, std, operator-keyword, stdmap, initializer-list

I was using initializer list to create object and assign it to the map with `int` key. In case of a simple structure the temporary structure can be created using initializer list.

hence me doing something like this is totally valid

```
struct fileJobPair {
        int file;
        int job;
};

map<int, fileJobPair> mp;
mp[1] = {10, 20};
mp[2] = {100, 200};
mp[3] = {1000, 2000};
```

But if I add constructor to the structure, I am getting error

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:18:21: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, fileJobPair>::mapped_type’ {aka ‘fileJobPair’} and ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’)
   18 |      mp[1] = {10, 20};
      |                     ^
file.cpp:4:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr AfileJobPair& AfileJobPair::operator=(const AfileJobPair&)’
    4 | struct fileJobPair {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
file.cpp:4:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const fileJobPair&’
file.cpp:4:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr fileJobPair& fileJobPair::operator=(fileJobPair&&)’
file.cpp:4:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘fileJobPair&&’
```

This is what I have tried :

```
struct fileJobPair {
        int file;
        int job;
        fileJobPair()
        {
                file = job = 0;
        }
};

int main()
{
            map<int, fileJobPair> mp;
            mp[1] = {10, 20};
            mp[2] = {100, 200};
            mp[3] = {1000, 2000};
            for(int i =1;i<=3;i++)
            {
                cout<< mp[i].file <<" "<< mp[i].job<<endl;
             }
            return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting error and how exactly is it working internally?

Comment: `fileJobPair` has a default constructor so you can't use initialisers to initialise it

Comment: This problem is only when I add constructor to this simple struct. SO exactly is it working internally

Comment: It's not the problem of the `map`. You will get the same with `fileJobPair f; f = {10,20};`. The difference is that once you add a custom default constructor, `fileJobPair` is no longer an _aggregate_. Look here for details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization.

Comment: @DanielLangr thanks a lot, that made my concept all clear. Please write an answer for it and I ll accept the same

Comment: @DanielLangr doesn't riquefr answer invalidates whatever the documentation says? "no user-declared constructors"

Comment: yup even I am not sure, @DanielLangr can you help here, how is it workng with parameterised constructor when the documentation says otherwise

Comment: @GBDGBDA No, the custom constructor just makes the class non-aggregate. But if you add a corresponding converting constructor, it will then be used for initialization. It is that constructors that takes two `int`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a new `fileJobPair`, it will use by default your empty constructor, so will not be available anymore to be completed with `{}`. But you can add a new constructor to it, that receive 2 integers and bind them to the respective values, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct fileJobPair {
        int file;
        int job;
        fileJobPair() {
            file = job = 0;
        }
        fileJobPair(int a, int b) {
            file = a;
            job = b;
        }
};

int main()
{
            map<int, fileJobPair> mp; 
            mp[1] = {10,10};
            mp[2] = {100, 200};
            mp[3] = {1000, 2000};
            for(int i =1;i<=3;i++)
            {
                cout<< mp[i].file <<" "<< mp[i].job<<endl;
             }
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh, but how is this working when the documentation says `no user-declared constructors
no user-provided constructors `

Comment: I don't know about the implementation on the C++ language that allows it, but I think it's because it now knows that you can use a 2 integer value to initialize the struct, when you use the empty constructor, it has no way to know that.